# beamerpost fontsize

Tags: beamer, fontsize

I am using beamerpost for my poster. I found out how I manage to change the font size of my body. Is it possible to change the font size of title, subtitle, etc. independently  as well? if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean `beamerposter` with `beamerpost`, you can use `\setbeamerfont` for the individual fonts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerposter}

\title{text}
\subtitle{subtitle}

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\fontsize{86pt}{92pt}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\fontsize{72pt}{76pt}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```